# Test a onClose callback from dialog when using material UI & react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm currently trying to get complete test coverage on my react app however I'm stuck with jest when trying to test the callback event params from material UI components.

I thought by testing the escape event I could cover the `onClose` parameter but it is still showing as untested.

Example of that test:

```
function renderWithRedux(
  ui: any,
  startingState: any = initialState,
  store?: any
) {
  if (!store) {
    store = createStore(reducer, startingState);
  }
  return {
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>),
    // adding `store` to the returned utilities to allow us
    // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
    // this to test implementation details).
    store,
  };
}


test("Should close the dialog on exit event eg esc key pressed", () => {
  const { container, queryByTestId } = renderWithRedux(
    <PermissionGroupList />,
    permissionGroupCat
  );
  fireEvent(
    queryByTestId("add-group"),
    new MouseEvent("click", {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    })
  );
  let dialogBox = queryByTestId("add-group-dialog");

  // Check that the dialog is open.
  expect(dialogBox).toBeTruthy();
  // Check that the dialog it closes.
  fireEvent.keyDown(document.body, {
    key: "Escape",
    keyCode: 27,
    which: 27
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Try to re get the element.
    dialogBox = queryByTestId("add-group-dialog");
    expect(dialogBox).toBeNull();
  }, 500);
})
```

Same or similar issue when passing the bound `closeDialog` method to the child component. It appears as untested. How would I test this / will it be covered with the tests of the children component if it fires the method (on the child), I have not yet created the child component tests.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above both these lines come back as untested, so how do I cover these with my tests.

I'm using react-testing-library and jest --coverage with redux and react-redux.

Answer (score 0):

Your running async code in a sync test. If you use `setTimeout` in your test then you need to pass in a `done()` function and then call it when your last async event has finished.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not creating arrow functions as props. Here's a more detailed explanation of the the drawbacks and alternate approaches:
https://medium.com/@oleg008/arrow-functions-in-react-f782d11460b4

This would also make it so those props would be covered by your tests. Though you may also need to test that the class method `handleGroupDialog` is called. You can do this with a spy:
https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/06/13/spyon-react-class-method/

David is also right! You'll want to use a done method or convert your test to async and await.

Comment: Article two contains a solution without removing arrow functions, and the first article seems like there is a minor  argument for compiling but seems it suggests its personal preference mainly?